# JavaScript Addition Operators not work

Tags: javascript

I try using javascript but the addition is not correct, live code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b39Lz/31/)

```
function hitung2() {
    var a = $(".a2").val();
    var b = $(".b2").val();
    c = a * b; //a kali b
    d = c + a;
    $(".c2").val(c);
    $(".d2").val(d);  
}
```

Comment: use `parseInt()` function like this: http://jsfiddle.net/b39Lz/33/

Comment: if your're going to work with fraction, see my answer also

Answer (score 2):

```
function hitung2() {
    var a = parseInt($(".a2").val());
    var b = parseInt($(".b2").val());
    c = a * b; //a kali b
    d = c + a;
    $(".c2").val(c);
    $(".d2").val(d);  
}
```

Or if you going to work with fractions then use `parseFloat()` function in same way as it described above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the string that you get from `.val` to `ints` with `parseInt()`

```
 var a = parseInt($(".a2").val());
 var b = parseInt($(".b2").val());
```

Updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/b39Lz/32/

Answer (score 0):

use parseInt()

```
  var a = $(".a2").val();
    var b = $(".b2").val();

    temp1=parseInt(a);
    temp2=parseInt(b);

    c = temp1 * temp2; 
    d = c + temp1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are String, so it uses String + operator, does concatenating the value. Convert string to int using: parseInt("10")

```
function hitung2() {
    var a = $(".a2").val();
    var b = $(".b2").val();
    c = a * b; //a kali b
    d = parseInt(c) + parseInt(a);
    $(".c2").val(c);
    $(".d2").val(d);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using parseInt() if you dont want to stick to integer calculations only.Try casting to general Number.

```
function hitung2() {
    var a =Number( $(".a2").val());
    var b = Number($(".b2").val());
    var c = a * b; //a kali b
    d =Number(c)+Number(a);
    $(".c2").val(c);
    $(".d2").val(d);  
}
```